# Clustering on Market-1501 dataset

Tags: clustering, machine-learning-model, pytorch

I am trying to perform clustering on the Market-1501 dataset. The approach that I am using is as follows:

1. I train a Person-Reid Model (using this repository: [Reid-Strong-Baseline](https://github.com/michuanhaohao/reid-strong-baseline))
2. Use a version of depth first search for clustering data (not part of the training set) into individual classes.

Although the Rank-1, Rank-5 metrics of the ReID model are very good, the overall effect of clustering is rather disappointing. I am also struggling to find relevant literature that could help me.

Does anyone have any pointers on where I could at least find relevant literature (i.e Person-Reid followed by clustering). Thanks in advance.

PS: I have posted the same question on Stackoverflow. Thought that this would be a more apt place for this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ReID output seems to be the right approach because you tell the network what to learn, but you have to choose the right output: it should be something like a softmax activation result telling the different possible classifications with scores.

Then, you can use that output to train dimensional reduction algorithms like UMAP or t-SNE: They have good results because they are non-linear, i.e. they are able the clusterize complex correlations between features.

Here is a playground:

https://projector.tensorflow.org/

Here is an interesting code with fashion images:

https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist

They have also a reproducibility function:

https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reproducibility.html

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas. Architecture used:
ResNet->Linear layer_1 (2048,512)-> Linear layer_2(512, num_classes)
Triplet Loss,Centre Loss are used on Linear layer_1 (512 features) and Classification Loss is used on Linear layer_2.

The inference is carried out by extracting 512 features and computing a score between the images based on cosine similarity. 

Shouldn't the network should reduce the original image into the latent space(512 dimensions)? After scores are computed between all images, I simply treat the problem as a graph clustering problem. Not sure where UMAP, t-SNE fits into this.

Comment: You should use UMAP on linear layer 2, but maybe it could be better on another layer: I don't know the precise layers output to give you the right answer. Nevertheless, here is an illustration of how UMAP works on ResNet according to each layer (see right side). I hope it would be clear enough: https://umap-tour.github.io/resnet50.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the link. If I understand clearly, you are suggesting that I use UMAP or t-SNE on the output of  the first/second linear layer to reduce the dimensions to a lower value. Followed by this I should run an unsupervised clustering algorithm (such as K-Means or DBSCAN) to get the actual clusters?

Comment: That’s it. The advantage of dim reduction is to compress very high dimensions like 512 to 2 or 3. You can even display pictures instead of dots thanks to their ID to see if it works well or not. Keep in mind that parameters should be tuned in some cases. https://pair-code.github.io/understanding-umap/

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. However, UMAP/t-SNE is simply for vizualization purposes right? Wouldn't it always be better if I perform clustering directly on the higher dimensional data rather than reducing it to a lower dimension(2 or 3) before performing the clustering?

Comment: Dim reduction is for visualization and data understanding because UMAP even places clusters in a meaningful way, and it is difficult for anyone to understand whether the results make sense or not. So it is an interesting clustering function, not just for visualisation. You can even detect outliers. That’s why you can color dots with the classification results, to see if all clusters have a good classification, and easily detect the ones that haven’t.